# How to prevent special characters from parsing/encoding in hyperlink URLs?

Tags: html, url, authentication, hyperlink, autocomplete

Is it possible to prevent special character from being encoded into an escape character?

For example, I have a URL that contains the necessary parameters for the user to auto login to somewhere like so:

https://www.mysecurepage.com/Login/login.aspx?lang=en&un=user1+test@gmail.com&pw=mypassword

So after user click on that hyperlink on the page, it says the credentials are incorrect because it tried to log them in as user1%2Btest@gmail.com. So its just putting a %2B where the + (plus) sign is supposed to be.

Anyway around that in hyperlinks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In an encoded URL, the `+` sign represents a space. If you want to preserve the `+` sign, you need to encode it as `%2B`. So the URL would look like this:

```
https://www.mysecurepage.com/Login/login.aspx?lang=en&un=user1%2Btest%40gmail.com&pw=mypassword
```